# MapInfo 12 problems with PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, mapinfo

I am simply trying to connect MapInfo 12 to my existing PostGIS database but after hours of trying various options I have hit a brick wall and need help. So far I have:

```
1) Downloaded and installed the 32bit ODBC PostrgeSQL driver
2) Open MapInfo 12 and enabled DBMS Catalog via the Tool Manager
3) In the DBMS Catalog I created Create Catalog>ODBC from the drop down
4) Select Data Source clicked the Machine Data Source > New and then User Data Source then scrolled to the bottom of the list to find PostgreSQL ANSI/Unicode options - I picked Unicode
5) In the dialog box I filled in my PostGIS conneciton details and hit test, and it successfully connected
6) Back in MapInfo I choose EasyLoader from the Tools list and and hit the ODBC button in the dialogue, then Machine Data Source and from the list pick PostgreSQL
7) Back in the EasyLoader dialog at the bottom i click Map Catolog' which successfully creates the mapinfo schema and table in my PostGIS database.
```

Then this is where it goes wrong, it now seems I need to make each table mappable

```
1) Table>Maintenance>Make DBMS table mappable>ODBC connection and again choose my PostgreSQL from the Machine Data Source
2) The new dialog box opens and it has all of my schemas and tables avaliable
3) I select one of the tables and click Open
4) In the Make Mappable dialog box I have 
Index Type: PostGIS
Index Column: the drop down list is empty and this is where I think there is a problem
```

If I choose Index Type: MapInfo the Index Column comes up with geom which is my geometry column but it also populates the X and Y column as though it is trying to find cooridnates to make the geometry.

My PostGIS geometries are standard Point, Lines, Polygons, MultiLineStrings and Multi Polygons

Does anyone know how to make a table mappable?

I am on MapInfo 12.02, PostgreSQL 9.3 64Bit and PostGIS 2.1

I have hundreds of tables to map, so surely there is a better way

Thanks

Comment: MapInfo requires the MapInfo.MapInfo_MapCatalog Table (Easyloader creates this) related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86654/will-mapinfo-only-read-postgis-data-that-has-been-loaded-via-easyloader

Comment: @Mapperz I successfully did that, its point 7) in my list, and the schema and table was successfully created. But it seems it is empty until i make the tables mappable. Have you managed to get it to work? thanks

Comment: Think you need the 32 Postgis 2.1 install as  the driver is only 32 bit http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg93/ (postgis-bundle-pg93x32-setup-2.1.3-1.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, latest MapInfo v12.0.3 still does NOT support PostGIS 2.1 - only 2.0.x versions are supported.

Second, if you could do a downgrade to 2.0.x (currently 2.0.6) version of PostGIS, then choose PostgreSQL ANSI ODBC driver v9.01.02, which is also officially latest supported driver version (MapInfo also doesnt support UNICODE).

I am working with 12.0.3 + PostGIS 2.0.6 +  ANSI ODBC driver v9.01.02 and there is no problem with procedure you described above.

Comment: If you solve "make dbms table mappable" problem then I assume you want to automate this process ?

Comment: Myself and all the team I work with are using PostGIS 2.1 so I guess it will have to wait to fully implement. However, I will try and test your answer on a different machine just to check it works. Thanks